# symfony 2 error - persisting data to a database

Tags: symfony

I get a message : "Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused" when persisting data to a database. Here is a controller:

```php
public function registerAction()
{
    $register = new Register();
    $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $register);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') 
    {
        $form->bindRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) 
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($register);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('ShopMyShopBundle_register'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('ShopMyShopBundle:Main:register.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
}
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Have you checked your logs? What do they say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided is not enough to find the reason. You should develop using the dev environment to see detailed error messages. To do it, access your app with the `app_dev.php` front controller. See [the section on environments](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/page_creation.html#environments).

Comment: When I use the app_dev.php front controller everything works, a data from a form is persisted to a database.

Comment: Then you need to clear the cache for the prod environment. Use `rm -rf app/cache/*` or `app/console cache:clear --env=prod`.